# AFTER INSERT TRIGGER en MYSQL actualiza todas las filas de la tabla

Tags: mysql, trigger, update

En mi base de datos, cree un after insert trigger que debería actualizar las filas de mi tabla "test" que tengan un cierto id_cart. Sin embargo, mi trigger esta actualizando todas las filas de la tabla test, incluso las que no cuentan con el id_cart correspondiente.
Este es mi trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `update_price_row` AFTER INSERT ON `test_product_quantity_cart`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
update test set total= (select sum(price_product) 
from test_product_quantity_cart where id_cart = new.id_cart);

END
```

El comportamiento que espero de este trigger es que, en mi tabla "test", solo se actualicen las filas cuyo id_cart sea igual a new.id_cart.
No estoy seguro de si mi update statement esta escrito de la forma correcta para indicar que actualice la columna "total" de la tabla "test" donde el id_cart sea igual a new.id_cart.
Lo anterior, debido a que si bien tengo un WHERE dentro del SELECT, ese WHERE indica al SELECT statement que sume la columna product_price de la tabla test_product_quantity_cart donde el id_cart sea igual a new.id_cart.
Mi impresion es que deberia usar un segundo WHERE para el UPDATE statement pero no se como hacerlo.
Gracias por su ayuda.

Edicion:
Este es el trigger cuando le agrego un where statement fuera del select:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `update_price_row` AFTER INSERT ON `test_product_quantity_cart`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
update test set total= (select sum(price_product) 
from test_product_quantity_cart where id_cart = new.id_cart) where id_cart=new.id_cart;

END
```

Este es el mensaje de error que obtengo en mysql workbench al modificar el trigger:

```
Executing:
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tienda_online`.`update_price_row`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `tienda_online`$$
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `tienda_online`.`update_price_row` AFTER INSERT ON `test_product_quantity_cart` FOR EACH ROW PRECEDES `test_product_quantity_cart_AFTER_INSERT`
$$
DELIMITER ;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tienda_online`.`test_product_quantity_cart_AFTER_INSERT`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `tienda_online`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `tienda_online`.`test_product_quantity_cart_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `test_product_quantity_cart` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

END
$$
DELIMITER ;

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
SQL Statement:
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `tienda_online`.`update_price_row` AFTER INSERT ON `test_product_quantity_cart` FOR EACH ROW PRECEDES `test_product_quantity_cart_AFTER_INSERT`
```

Comment: El primer `where` aplica para la sub-consulta. Si quieres restringir los registros a actualizar debes poner un `where` por fuera, algo como: `update test set total= (select sum(price_product) 
from test_product_quantity_cart where id_cart = new.id_cart) WHERE laColumna=new.id_cart;` NO olvides cambiar `laColumna` por el nombre real de la columna en la tabla `test` que debería coincidir con el nuevo `id_cart`.

Comment: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `update_price_row` AFTER INSERT ON `test_product_quantity_cart`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
update test set total= (select sum(price_product) 
from test_product_quantity_cart where id_cart = new.id_cart) where id_cart=new.id_cart;

END

Comment: Estoy tratando de implementar justamente esa solucion pero cuando aplico los cambios al trigger, recibo un mensaje de error: hay un error con la sintaxis de mi sql. Sin embargo, no me dice cual es el error.

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta el texto completo del mensaje de error, pulsando en [edit].